# How to save remote push notifications when app is in the background

Tags: ios, swiftui, core-data, push-notification, firebase-cloud-messaging

In the app I am able to save remote notifications sent from FCM. I am currently saving them to both coredata and Firestore Database for testing. The problem comes down to the notification only being able to save to both either coredata and Firestore when the app is open or I interact with the notification. This is where thees two methods come into play:

```
func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
    
    if let notificationDict = userInfo["aps"] as? [String: AnyObject],
       let alertDict = notificationDict["alert"] as? [String: AnyObject],
       let title = alertDict["title"] as? String,
       let body = alertDict["body"] as? String {
        saveNotificationToCoreData(title: title, body: body)
    }
    
    saveNotificationToFirestore(userInfo)

    completionHandler([.alert, .sound])
}


func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo

    if let notificationDict = userInfo["aps"] as? [String: AnyObject],
       let alertDict = notificationDict["alert"] as? [String: AnyObject],
       let title = alertDict["title"] as? String,
       let body = alertDict["body"] as? String {
        saveNotificationToCoreData(title: title, body: body)
    }

    saveNotificationToFirestore(userInfo)

    completionHandler()
}
```

Otherwise when the app is in the background or closed, and I send a new notification through FCM and directly open the app without interacting with the notification, the notification does not get saved to either database.
I've read on changing my payload to "content-available": 1 to be able to send background notifications and for the app to refresh in the background but there is no way to change the default payload in the FCM dashboard.

I am not sure if I am missing a method to achieve this in my appDelegate or if i really need to set up a server side file in order to send custom notifications where I have access to changing the payload.

Here is my full AppDelegate class for more context:

```
import SwiftUI
import FirebaseCore
import UserNotifications
import UIKit
import Firebase
import FirebaseFirestore
import FirebaseMessaging
import FirebaseAnalytics
import CoreData



 @main
 struct PGUApp: App {
@UIApplicationDelegateAdaptor(AppDelegate.self) var appDelegate
let persistenceController = PersistenceController.shared




var body: some Scene {
    WindowGroup {
        ContentView().environment(\.managedObjectContext, 
persistenceController.persistentContainer.viewContext)

    }
}
}


class AppDelegate: UIResponder, UIApplicationDelegate, 
UNUserNotificationCenterDelegate, MessagingDelegate {


let gcmMessageIDKey = "gcm.message_id"


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey: Any]? = nil) -> Bool {
    print("Application didFinishLaunchingWithOptions called")
    

    FirebaseApp.configure()


    let center = UNUserNotificationCenter.current()
     center.requestAuthorization(options: [.alert, .badge, .sound]) { granted, error in
         if let error = error {
             print("Authorization request error: \(error)")
         } else {
             print("Authorization granted: \(granted)")
             if granted {
                 DispatchQueue.main.async {
                     application.registerForRemoteNotifications()
                 }
             } else {
                 print("User denied notification permissions")
                 // Handle the denial of permissions here
             }
         }
     }
     center.delegate = self


    Messaging.messaging().delegate = self
  

    return true
 
}

func applicationDidBecomeActive(_ application: UIApplication) {

}


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithDeviceToken deviceToken: Data) {
    Messaging.messaging().apnsToken = deviceToken
    print("APNs device token retrieved: \(deviceToken)")
}

func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFailToRegisterForRemoteNotificationsWithError error: Error) {
    print("Failed to register for remote notifications: \(error.localizedDescription)")
}


func messaging(_ messaging: Messaging, didReceiveRegistrationToken fcmToken: String?) {
  print("FCM Token received: \(fcmToken ?? "nil")")
    
    if let token = fcmToken {
           saveTokenToFirestore(token)
       }
    
}

func saveTokenToFirestore(_ token: String) {
    // Assuming you have a `userId` to associate with the token
    let userId = "someUserId" // Replace with actual user ID
    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    db.collection("user_tokens").document(userId).setData(["fcmToken": token]) { error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error saving token to Firestore: \(error)")
        } else {
            print("Token successfully saved to Firestore")
        }
    }
    
}


func application(_ application: UIApplication, didReceiveRemoteNotification userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any], fetchCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UIBackgroundFetchResult) -> Void) {


}


func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            willPresent notification: UNNotification,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping (UNNotificationPresentationOptions) -> Void) {
    let userInfo = notification.request.content.userInfo
    
    if let notificationDict = userInfo["aps"] as? [String: AnyObject],
       let alertDict = notificationDict["alert"] as? [String: AnyObject],
       let title = alertDict["title"] as? String,
       let body = alertDict["body"] as? String {
        saveNotificationToCoreData(title: title, body: body)
    }
    
    saveNotificationToFirestore(userInfo)

    completionHandler([.alert, .sound])
}


func userNotificationCenter(_ center: UNUserNotificationCenter,
                            didReceive response: UNNotificationResponse,
                            withCompletionHandler completionHandler: @escaping () -> Void) {
    let userInfo = response.notification.request.content.userInfo

    if let notificationDict = userInfo["aps"] as? [String: AnyObject],
       let alertDict = notificationDict["alert"] as? [String: AnyObject],
       let title = alertDict["title"] as? String,
       let body = alertDict["body"] as? String {
        saveNotificationToCoreData(title: title, body: body)
    }

    saveNotificationToFirestore(userInfo)

    completionHandler()
}



func saveNotificationToFirestore(_ userInfo: [AnyHashable: Any]) {
    guard let aps = userInfo["aps"] as? [String: AnyObject],
          let alert = aps["alert"] as? [String: String],
          let title = alert["title"],
          let body = alert["body"] else {
        print("Invalid notification content")
        return
    }

    let db = Firestore.firestore()
    let notificationData: [String: Any] = [
        "title": title,
        "body": body,
        "timestamp": FieldValue.serverTimestamp(),
    ]
    
    db.collection("notifications").addDocument(data: notificationData) { error in
        if let error = error {
            print("Error saving notification to Firestore: \(error)")
        } else {
            print("Notification successfully saved to Firestore")
        }
    }

}




func saveNotificationToCoreData(title: String, body: String) {
    let context = PersistenceController.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let newNotification = Notifi(context: context)
    newNotification.title = title
    newNotification.body = body

    do {
        try context.save()
    } catch {
        print("Failed to save notification: \(error)")
    }
    
    printAllNotifications()
}


func printAllNotifications() {
    let context = PersistenceController.shared.persistentContainer.viewContext
    let fetchRequest: NSFetchRequest<Notifi> = Notifi.fetchRequest()

    do {
        let notifications = try context.fetch(fetchRequest)
        for notification in notifications {
            print("Title: \(notification.title ?? "Unknown Title"), Body: \(notification.body ?? "No Body")")
        }
    } catch let error as NSError {
        print("Could not fetch. \(error), \(error.userInfo)")
    }
}
```

}

If anyone can shine some light, I would really appreciate it.

Comment: Have you included the "Background Fetch" and "Remote Notifications" capabilities in your app?